# java library for drawing graph

Tags: java, swing, graph

I have seen many discussion in stackoverflow about libraries, and i didn't come to a decision.

Because i'm looking for something to fit my specific task.

To explain:

I have a homework for implementing belmanford algorithm(shortest path in a graph),and i want to use a library to represent the graph(vertices and edges) ,**the library have just to color the shortest path from one vetex to another(just this task no more).**

If any one can help me especially if you have already used the library , i have just 2 days to make the representation.(note that **i have already coded the algorithm, the library has to interact with my program**)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not the easiest to use, but for the description that you gave I would go with the [Java Graphics API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), you can easily find examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a tool that gives you much flexibility in drawing complex graphs, then I see [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is the best option available as it has many features and well-documented.

The down side of this is that you need to write the graph files (`.dot` format) yourself. This isn't difficult and you can even automate it. Assuming you already have installed Graphviz and `dot` command  located in `/usr/local/bin/dot`, then you can simply run this within your java program

```
    String dot="digraph{ a->b b->c a->c }";
    BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.dot"));
    br.write(dot);
    br.flush();
    br.close();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/dot -Tpdf  test.dot -o dotTest.pdf" );
```

This will output `pdf` file. Other formats are also possible (i.e. `gif`, `png` ..etc).